# Error while starting ADB in Eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse, shell

This is certainly a repeated question, I have seen and tried many answers. When I try to deploy an android application, I am getting error as -

```
------------------------------
Android Launch!
The connection to adb is down, and a severe error has occured.
You must restart adb and Eclipse.
Please ensure that adb is correctly located at 'D:\Android SDK 22.6.2\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe' and can be executed.
```

I tried -

1. adb kill-server
2. restart eclipse
3. adb start-server
4. Checked adb is located in platform-tools and same path is updated in eclipse SDK location also
5. Started adb.exe from cmd to run adb devices where I can see my devices (they are offline)
6. Went to windows task manager and killed adb.exe process and restarted eclipse again.

Even after all these steps, I am unable to start adb from eclipse. In run configurations also, I have launch configuration with actual package name. 
I can start the Emulator separately from ADB Devices dialog in eclipse, but the device is always offline. I am not sure where I am going wrong in this part. Can any one please help me out of this?

Please let me know in case of any additional details required.

Comment: Sometimes I get device offline when using front USB with low quality cables... Try to reboot your device as well, change the cable and USB port.

Comment: Usually killing the adb process fixes it for me... I assume you enabled ADB debugging on the device? Also, not all USB cables support data, they just charge.

Comment: Only one thing to say... please migrate to AndroidStudio

Comment: Are you using Linux?

Answer (score 0):

Finally, after installing Android Studio, the problem was solved. Thanks @An-driod